# DataSet Relation over Multiple columns

Tags: asp.net, dataset, relation, multiple-columns

I'm having a hard time setting relation between my tables in my dataset. I got 2 repeaters (nested). RepeaterReplies is the outer repeater. Here is where I bind it and set the relation.

Here is what I have

```
            List<DataColumn> parents = new List<DataColumn>{};
            parents.Add(ds.Tables[0].Columns["REPLY_ID"]);
            parents.Add(ds.Tables[0].Columns["USER_ID"]);
            List<DataColumn> childs = new List<DataColumn>{};
            childs.Add(ds.Tables[2].Columns["REPLY_ID"]);
            childs.Add(ds.Tables[2].Columns["MAKER_USER_ID"]);
            DataColumn[] parentz = parents.ToArray();
            DataColumn[] children = childs.ToArray();
            ds.Relations.Add("parents", parentz, children,false);
            repeaterReplies.DataSource = ds;
            repeaterReplies.DataBind();
```

When I check my dataset which contains 3 tables (I just need to set a relation between first and last table - tbl[0] and tbl[2]) and I'm sure that first table has the columns REPLY_ID and USER_ID and the 3rd table has REPLY_ID and MAKER_USER_ID.

I'm getting the error when binding the inner repeater (ItemDataBound of outer repeater)

```
                DataRowView dv = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
                Repeater nestedRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("repeaterComments") as Repeater;
                if (nestedRepeater != null)
                {
                    nestedRepeater.DataSource = dv.CreateChildView("replies");
                    nestedRepeater.DataBind();
                }
```

Error is

> The relation is not parented to the table to which this DataView
>   points.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried the [CreateChildView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/f1c1e9k5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method, but shouldn't you use the name you've defined in the [DataRelation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9ae5a582.aspx)?

```
nestedRepeater.DataSource = dv.CreateChildView("parents");
```